# How to enter various nvram boot-args

Tags: nvram

I'd like to set both vm_compression=1 plus serverperfmode=1. Can I achieve this by `nvram boot-args "vm_compression=1","serverperfmode=1"`

Answer (score 6):

If you want both arguments in one command, you can use a space to separate:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="vm_compression=1 serverperfmode=1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Guess I found a way to do it. Open Terminal and run

```
sudo nvram boot-args="vm_compressor=1"
sudo nvram boot-args="$(nvram boot-args) serverperfmode=1"
```

then use `nvram boot-args` to check

```
$ nvram boot-args       
boot-args       vm_compressor=1 serverperfmode=1
```